# Having a modal fade in after a JS setTimeout

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, transition

I've got the modal box appearing after 3 seconds as well as a black background set to 50% opacity. Right now the box and background just appears right at 3 seconds, I can't quite figure out how to have the opacity go from 0% (0.0) to 50% (0.5) starting at 3 seconds.

CSS:

```
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

JS:

```
const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

const span = document.querySelector(".close");

setTimeout(function () {
  modal.style.display = "flex";
}, 3000);

span.onclick = () => {
  modal.style.display = "none";
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an animation to get around the item being display none

```js
document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector('.modal').classList.toggle("show");
});
```

```css
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  right: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #CCC;
  display: none;
}

.modal.show {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: showModal;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes showModal {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  XXXXXXX
</div>

<button id="btn">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS

```
     #myModal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 5s;
  transition-delay: 3s;
}
```

it will fade in opacity

Here are the bugs with your code. Your css was a class and not an ID. So, JS could not find the ID to trigger.

I changed that to the ID name as defined in your JS

Comment: *animation:show 2s 3s forwards;

Comment: Looks like opacity: 0 is causing the entire modal to not appear, setting it to another value, i.e 50, just leads to the modal appearing right at 3 seconds without any transition.